# Где нужны запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

*Но особое предпочтение я отдаю танцам.*

Comment: Чтобы получить развернутый ответ, пожалуйста, изложите Ваши сомнения.

Answer (score 5):

Не представляю, где тут можно попытаться поставить запятую.

Запятых не нужно.